# Elgg, how to get all actions?

Tags: elgg

i need to register to the events of the actions in elgg framework
( like making a post or adding a friend) 
Is there a way of doing so ?

Answer (score 2):

In the bundled Developer Tools plugin you can inspect all registered actions, [events](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Elgg_Events), and [plugin hooks](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Plugin_Hooks) and what handler functions are bound to them. You can use functions like elgg_register_event_handler and elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler to register callbacks on events/hooks that occur.

Answer (score 0):

Actions like posting a blog or making a comment can be registered into the Elgg actions system through this API (eventually saved in $CONFIG->actions as an array):

```
elgg_register_action($action, $filename = "", ...)
```

After you have registered an action, you can perform it by the URL http://elggsite.org/action/action_name/ either through form post or ajax.

The action_name url segment correspond to the first parameter passed in the elgg_register_action() API.

Furthermore, you can dump all actions registered into Elgg by

```
var_dump($CONFIG->actions);
```

after Elgg finishes booting.